# Publishing MVC app that uses python script

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I currently have MVC project that calls python script via Process (new processStartinfo("/path/to/python.exe", " /path/to/script.py"). Which works perfectly fine in visual studio. 
When i publish this on azure how will it be able to call python.exe? (Im probably not constructing this question accurately since this is my very first web to publish and do not have full understanding of publishing)

P.S. I did try to use IronPython but since my script uses NLTK, i ran into bunch of issues so it was easier to install python&nltk with pip, then call python.exe with through command line that takes argument of /path/to/script.py. Any input is appreciated.

EDIT: my homeController starts a process that passes in path_of_python, path_of_script to command line, redirects the output and does work on the data it gets back (from output).

Comment: It really depends on how you're doing this in Azure. Is it an Azure Website? A VM? Can you use Azure Functions? Does the Python code need to run on the exact same machine as the website?

Comment: I was thinking Azure website but coworker told me hes thinking it wont be possible that way but wasnt fully sure due to little python experience. I edited my question for more info. I dont have any preference with the way of publish, as long as it works.

Comment: You can't run separate processes in Azure websites as far as I'm aware. But nothing preventing you from using Azure Functions (Google it) or setting up a Python app somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be possible to use Python script with NLTK package in C# on Azure website.

I tried to implement it via a workaround way as below, and it works fine.

**Step 1. For installing Python & NLTK on Azure WebApp**

1. Access the Kudu tool of your webapp via the url `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`.
2. Install a site extension `Python 2.7.12 x86` which will be installed at the path `D:\home` if using the 32bit version of Azure WebApp as example.
   [image]
3. Switch to the Kudu CMD, then you can see a new Python runtime which has been installed at here and you have permission to do any operations on it.
   [image]
4. Commands `cd Python27` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via `Edit` button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the `pip` tool.
   [image]
5. Command `Scripts\pip install nltk` to install `nltk` package.
6. To download the nltk data, command `python -m nltk.downloader -d D:\home\Python27\nltk_data all` as below, please don't close the current browser window or switch other urls until the command completed
   [image]
   You can view the download task in process as below via the url `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/` at the other browser window.
   [image]
   6.1 Or you can download the nltk data on local to upload them into Azure WebApp.

**Step 2. For testing Python script with NLTK package**

1. Command `touch test.py` at the path `wwwroot`, and edit the content below.

   ```
   import nltk
   sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
   ... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
   tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
   print tokens
   ```
2. The console show the result as below, it works.
   [image]

**Step 3. Calls python script via `Process` in C#**

Just only using the absoulte path of python runtime & script `D:\home\Python27\python` & `D:\home\site\wwwroot\test.python` instead of them in your C# code.

Please try and feedback your result. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.