# Make .exe file from wxPython GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, exe, pyinstaller

I've trying to convert my simple wxpython GUI (mygui.py) to .exe file with pyinstaller and by running "pyinstaller mygui.py" everything goes ok, I got application (exe) file, but can't run, just open blank console. I'm sure something is pretty wrong I'm doing there, but I don't know what is it. Is there missing parameters I give, like output path? 
This is the first time I'm trying to make exe file, I don't know what else information to share with you...

Comment: have you tried using the latest version of pyinstaller from github? (`pip install -U git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git`). It's a general advise in case of obscure building problems.

Comment: I'm going to try now. One more question, maybe stupid, maybe not. Is it possible to make exe file on ubuntu (not running, just make it)? @9dogs

Comment: no, currently pyinstaller [can't do cross-compiling](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: There is no way to cross-compile with pyinstaller or any of the others (py2exe, cx_freeze, etc). You will also want to use the `-w` flag since this is a GUI app. See https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options for more info.

Comment: what are the modules you import ? it seems pyinstaller behaves depending on imported modules (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750676/build-a-exe-for-windows-from-a-python-3-script-importing-pyqtgraph-and-opening)