# Using Python and Flask in Azure cannot find the requests_file module

Tags: python, pandas, azure, python-requests

In Azure, using Python with the Flask and pandas modules to create a RESTful webservice.   Azure doesn't appear able to find the requests_file module.

Launching the web page keeps returning error: No module named requests_file

I have installed "requests" and "requests_file" manually using the Kudu CLI https://"yoursitename".scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole.

They both appear to be there.  What am I missing or is there a bug in Azure?

Comment: why dont you use requirements.txt?

Comment: Exhausted every google search recommendation.  So, certainly, I have put the string into  requirements.txt.  The module 'requests' is in the remote system, Azure  just seems to ignore it.

Comment: in this case i would ask if you are targeting the right version of python, you are probably targeting 3 and using 2 or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure your `requirements.txt` file in your flask project.

Put the list of your python modules in the `requirements.txt`
    requests==2.18.4

Install wheel module using below command

```
python.exe -m pip install wheel
```

Use Below Command to create wheel files inside wheelhouse folder in Local environment

```
python.exe -m pip wheel -r requirements.txt -w wheelhouse
```

Then upload your project to your azure web app.

You could use code as below to test requests module

```
import requests

r= requests.get("https://www.bing.com")
print r.status_code
```

More details , please refer to this [blog](https://prmadi.com/install-python-modules-on-azure-app-services/) and this thread: [Publishing MVC app that uses python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473801/publishing-mvc-app-that-uses-python-script)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: To fix this, you have ensure the web.config file points to the correct "site-packages" directory.  The default value is typically incorrect, especially if you add a new python version using Site Extension.