# Web2py project deployment on Azure app service

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web2py

I am currently using PythonAnywhere to deploy my web2py project, it is working fine for me.

Now I want to deploy my web2py application on azure App service. I followed all the steps mentioned in below Goggle group

> [Creating web apps with Web2py in Azure Web Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/web2py/azure/web2py/XGxM_Tb9nJ4/ItS8GF5oAgAJ)

Still I can see default page of azure python web app. I also tried to do it with same code base mentioned in given git repository.

I am unable to figure out which document I should refer or what are the right steps to deploy web2py project to Azure web app service.

---

Below are the steps I followed to deploy web2py project to Azure app service

1. Created Azure app service with P1V2 app service plan. Linux machine with python 3.6 default language
2. Selected local git repository in deployment center and pushed code to azure git repository. It shows deployment successful message

[image]

3. Browse azure website, but this time it is not showing expected landing page. It is showing me default app page of azure website

I tried steps 3-4 times but everytime I am getting same result. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the forum thread [`Creating web apps with Web2py in Azure Web Apps`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/web2py/azure/web2py/XGxM_Tb9nJ4/ItS8GF5oAgAJ) of Google Groups as you mentioned, I see there is a file named `web.config` in its attachments, as the figure below.

[image]

However, the discussion is too old at 2015-11-13. At that time, Azure only supports Windows for Azure App Services, but you were trying to reproduce it on Azure WebApp for Linux based on Docker, because `P1V2` Sku is for Linux and `Standard S1` for Windows, as the figures below.

`P1V2` Sku of Azure App Service Plan for Windows

[image]

`Standard S1` Sku of Azure App Service Plan for Windows

[image]

So if you want to reproduce the same application of the thread of Google Groups on Azure WebApp for Windows, please try to refer to my answer for the other SO thread [No pip or python module inside azure webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380612/no-pip-or-python-module-inside-azure-webapp/55381506#55381506). There is not any Azure offical document introduce how to deploy a Python application on Azure Windows WebApp.

Otherwise, please refer to the two Azure offical documents [`Quickstart: Create a Python app in Azure App Service on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash) and [`Configure a Linux Python app for Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python) to try to change and deploy it on Azure Webapp for Linux. Even that you need to follow the document [`Configure a custom Linux container for Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container) to create a custom docker image for deployment.

Comment: Superb Peter, it worked. Thanks a lot. I used windows operating system and used sample app deployment now I can see Default landing page.. Cheers.. Once I am done with complete deployment I will write blog and will share with you.. Thanks a lot